# Updating `enterKeyHint` resets the input value on Chrome Android

Tags: javascript, android, dom, input, android-softkeyboard

I'm updating the value of [`enterKeyHint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/enterKeyHint) dynamically in an autocomplete library. When there's a active item, the `Enter` key should use "go" (to hint that hitting `Enter` navigates to the item's link) and when there isn't (no query, no results), the `Enter` key should use "search".

This DOM updates works fine on most mobile browsers, **except on Chrome Android.** When the update happens, the input value is cleared.

I've [reproduced the issue in isolation](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-tesla-eyxlxz?file=/src/index.js). The update kicks in at 5 characters.

Here are quick previews on a Galaxy S9:

With Firefox Android, the `Enter` key's label updates as expected and the input value doesn't change.

[image: Expected behavior on Firefox Android]

With Chrome Android, the `Enter` key updates but the input value is reset (causing new updates to the `Enter` key, etc.)

[image: Unexpected behavior on Chrome Android]

I'm suspecting an inconsistency between how mobile browsers implement the spec, since everything works as expected on Safari iOS, Chrome iOS and Firefox Android. However, I couldn't find anything online, it doesn't seem like this behavior has been reported before (I assume updating this propery isn't too commonplace).

**Has anyone ever faced this issue, or understands it?** Thanks in advance!